# Change query value url using replaceState()

Tags: javascript, firefox, replace

I have 
`http://localhost:8000/config/users/list.php?status=on&filter=`

when I change my input need replace filter value without refreshing the page

`$('#input-filter').on('input', function() {
      history.replaceState({status: 1, filter: 1}, "title", "list.php");
});`

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
$('#input-filter').on('input', function() { 
    history.replaceState({ status: 1, filter: $(this).val() }, "title", "list.php"); 
});
```